# Help with 2-week plan for learning Spring and OSGi

Tags: java, spring, maven, osgi

I've been a .NET developer for a couple of years and am moving into some Java work. It's been a couple years since I've used Java, which was in college, and then I didn't have experience using various frameworks - I've only learned enough to get through your usual computer science courses.

I need to gain an in-depth understanding of both the Spring Framework and OSGi framework. I have about 2 weeks to do this, so I am just looking for some guidance - something of a syllabus even - for how to spend my time over those 2 weeks.

It's been suggested I start with Spring, but how much time should I spend with each? 1-week spring, 1-week osgi? 12 days spring + 2 days osgi?, etc...

I will be using Eclipse as my development environment. The easiest way for me to learn is usually from books that start with small sample projects that compile and work, and progressively become larger or cover new concepts in later chapters.

From my research, this seems to be a good start for Spring: [Spring into Action 3rd edition](http://www.manning.com/walls4)

I've searched for OSGi books on Amazon.com and see that there are books that cover OSGi specifically and some that cover it in conjunction with Spring.

I have 2 weeks allocated to learn as much as I can about both, and would like learn as efficiently as possible. Any suggestions on a 2 week plan, citing specific resources to use (internet, ebooks, etc...) and chapters to go through (e.g. first 7 chapters of Spring in Action)?

Obviously, I can put together a plan myself, but I still would like to have input from developers who've had experience with the frameworks and can tell me the most important topics to cover in each subject area, as I'm totally new to both frameworks.

Comment: If you are not experienced with the tools you may need to spend more time getting up to speed than you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I always have time to continually learn, but for now I am looking for help on an intensive way to learn the most important concepts for both frameworks. But for all I know, what I've said could be too optimistic. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a little sample tutorial i put together for osgi. It certainly doesn't give you enough info to be an expert in OSGI, but it might cut through alot of the mystifying lingo that you will find at the official sites.

http://www.jroller.com/dbrosius/entry/osgi_spring_dm_w_o

Comment: wow!!! this is certainly the best tutorial on SpringDM-OSGI Integration I ever read!!....step by step and reasoning for every step. Thanks a ton MeBigFatGuy! this really got me started on my project. I was able to run the code from the zip file after going through step by step explanation.